# Amazon AWS RDS MySQL Role Privileges not cascading

Tags: mysql, rds

I have an RDS instance of MySQL 8.0.13 where I am trying to implement Roles based permissions so I don't have to create / alter each user individually.

Here is the code I am using...

```
GRANT ROLE_ADMIN ON *.* TO mymasteruser; -- Need to do this or line 5 doesn't work.
CREATE ROLE 'TEST_ROLE';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_data.* TO 'TEST_ROLE';
CREATE USER 'dev3'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$uper$ecretP@ssw0rd';
GRANT TEST_ROLE TO 'dev3'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I don't get any error messages when I run the above code, but when I try to login to the db using dev3 I get an Access Denied for user 'dev3'@'%' to database 'test_data'.

When I run

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR TEST_ROLE
```

I get

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `TEST_ROLE`@`%`
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_data`.* TO `TEST_ROLE`@`%`
```

When I run

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'dev3'@'%'
```

I get

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `dev3`@`%`
GRANT `TEST_ROLE`@`%` TO `dev3`@`%`
```

It looks to me that all the correct permissions are in place, but I still get Access Denied.

I can give that user individual access as normal, just not through the role.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `GRANT ROLE_ADMIN ON *.* TO mymasteruser;` saved a day for me :D

Answer (score 2):

After some research the answer seems to be to run

```
SET DEFAULT ROLE 'TEST_ROLE' TO 'dev3'@'%';
```